# Keep a Java Collection sorted in a difficult Scenario efficiently

Tags: java, performance, sorting, collections

Which Java Collection should I use if I have a lot of Objects with slowly changing keys?
Basically I have one ArrayList that has all the Objects that need sorting. That ArrayList is changed by an other Thread sometimes. To iterate over it I have written the ArrayList to another ArrayList with clear and then addAll until now, but I now realized that can also cause the ConcurrentModificationException, so I want to change that.

That new Collection (currently ArrayList) that I use for iteration needs to be sorted with a custom Comparator. The problem is that, before I make the next copy of the original, the keys will change and I will have to sort it multiple times. The order for these sorts is almost correct already usually. An insertion sort may be good here.
The big question now is:

1. Do I use TreeSet and call Collections.sort on it when the order changed
2. Do I use some kind of List (which kind? ArrayList? LinkedList?) and call Collections.sort when order changed

I think the correct answer for this question can only be given when considering that I have to copy an other unsorted Collection first (ArrayList, but not necessarily) and do that while the Data in the Collection is changed by an other Thread.

My thoughts on the solution are following:

1. Have the second Collection be a ArrayList and update it always with Collections.copy (making it the right size first, but it should usually be the right size already in my scenario (I realize this is not atomic and can cause issues)), then call Collections.sort on it as often as I want. Maybe implement insertion sort algorithm for every sort after the initial sort, because it should be faster then.
2. Use TreeSet for the second collection somehow. The problem is I don't know how I would iterate over the original threadsafe to add all the elements from there. Also I don't know how to sort the Set after that initialization efficiently. I saw someone use Collections.sort, but I don't know about efficiency there. Also remember it is almost sorted.

What you need to also keep in mind, I only need iterating over both, the original and the working copy Collection, no indexing is necessary.

I have made some Java Code to show the Problem now:

```
public static List<FloatWrapper> pending_additions = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
public static List<FloatWrapper> pending_removals = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());

public static List<FloatWrapper> list = new ArrayList<>();

public static Random rnd = new Random();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // initialize array
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        list.add(new FloatWrapper(i));
    }
    // the main loop (runs basically infinitly)
    for (int runs_infinitly = 0; runs_infinitly < 100; runs_infinitly++) {
        // apply pending changes
        synchronized (pending_additions) {
            list.addAll(pending_additions);
            pending_additions.clear();
        }
        synchronized (pending_removals) {
            list.removeAll(pending_removals);
            pending_removals.clear();
        }

        // doing my stuff
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            // sort array with quicksort I believe, which is not the fastest
            // for this scenario usually, except for the start when its completly unsorted
            System.out.println("sorting");
            Collections.sort(list);
            // iterate very often doing different things
            for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
                for (FloatWrapper num : list) {
                    // do something with num
                    System.out.print(num.number + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
            System.out.println("changing keys");
            // change the values that are used for sorting
            for (FloatWrapper num : list) {
                num.number += (rnd.nextFloat() - 0.5f) * 0.2f;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class FloatWrapper implements Comparable<FloatWrapper> {
    public float number;

    public FloatWrapper(float number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    public int compareTo(FloatWrapper arg0) {
        return Float.compare(number, arg0.number);
    }
}
```

The Arrays pending_additions and pending_removals are the only ones written from an other Thread. They are my improvement since I wrote this post, so not the whole List needs to be copied and resorted.
My Question still stands, should I use a TreeSet to increase performance, should I do something else different? Basically I don't know about sorting a TreeSet efficiently. I could even imagine that the ArrayList with Collection.sort() is more efficient, but I don't know. Can someone explain that.

Also I'm using a custom Comparator which has even a little bit of maths in it so it is really benificial to optimize the process of sorting here

Comment: Some aspects of this "difficult" scenario are not entirely clear. So correct me where I'm wrong: You have a collection of the *unsorted* elements. You regularly need to iterate over these elements, in *sorted* order. The sorting key is changed by a thread, but it is changed rarely. Is there a reason to *not* keep the collection sorted in the first place? The formerly unsorted collection could become a `TreeSet`, and the changing thread could do `set.remove(element); changeKey(element); set.add(element);`, protected with some `ReadWriteLock`.

Comment: You have tried to play with synchronized methods/blocks to prevent your initial problem?

Comment: @Marco13 Almost every key changes between every sort call that I proposed, and it is changed from the same thread that needs to sort the list. The keys only change slightly though so the order is usually also just changed a little bit

Comment: It's hard (at least, nearly impossible for me) to make a profound statement or recommendation based on that description. When something like a list is "almost sorted", even the (otherwise often impractical) [Bubble Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) could be worth being considered. But there seem to be some subtleties regarding synchronization in your case. Maybe some pseudocode, with comments like `// This is called rarely/often by thread A/B` could help...?

Comment: @Marco13 I am working on it give me a few minutes and I will post some, I should have done that from the beginning on anyway

Comment: Have you actually identified sorting the list to be a performance bottleneck? Just how big is that list?

Comment: @meriton This is part of a physics engine and the sorting is done really often on like 1000 objects, maybe more, depending on the scene. I want to have all the performance that I can get. Especially since this seems to be one of the optimizable parts of the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current implementation *already* leverages that the list is partially sorted:

The Javadoc for `Collections.sort` writes

> This implementation defers to the List.sort(Comparator) method

and the Javadoc of that method [says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator))

> This implementation is a stable, adaptive, iterative mergesort that requires far fewer than n lg(n) comparisons when the input array is partially sorted, while offering the performance of a traditional mergesort when the input array is randomly ordered. If the input array is nearly sorted, the implementation requires approximately n comparisons. Temporary storage requirements vary from a small constant for nearly sorted input arrays to n/2 object references for randomly ordered input arrays.
>
> The implementation takes equal advantage of ascending and descending order in its input array, and can take advantage of ascending and descending order in different parts of the same input array. It is well-suited to merging two or more sorted arrays: simply concatenate the arrays and sort the resulting array.
>
> The implementation was adapted from Tim Peters's list sort for Python ( TimSort). It uses techniques from Peter McIlroy's "Optimistic Sorting and Information Theoretic Complexity", in Proceedings of the Fourth Annual ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms, pp 467-474, January 1993.

Since you are iterating over the collection far more often than sorting it, the iterations (and the actions therein) are likely far more costly than the sort. That is, you are unlikely to get a significant improvement by further tuning the sort.

Comment: since TreeSet is not usable right? Since you would always need to recreate it in n*log(n) time

Comment: A TreeSet would be a poor choice. It does not support mutable keys, does not support duplicate keys, and has much higher memory overhead (and therefore worse iteration performance) than an ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

What you really need is not exactly clear, but I think you should be fine with maintaining a `CopyOnWriteArrayList<T>`, which you then iterate with

```
list.stream().sorted(yourComparator).forEach(yourAction);
```

The `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is thread-safe, ie if some other thread changes it while the iteration is going, you won't get a `ConcurrentModificationException` and continue iterating the list as it was when you started.

EDIT: Or, since you want to iterate several times:

```
List<FloatWrapper> sorted = list.stream().sorted().collect(toList());
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { sorted.forEach(i -> doYourStuff(i)); }
```

Comment: this would be perfect if I had to only iterate once, but I have multiple iteration calls (actually like 10 or more) and for every of them the collection is not allowed to change. Only at specific positions the changes need to be applied to the iterating arraylist. I'm sorry for being unclear, maybe I should put code in my post next time to show the problem

Comment: @HenrikD Then what about collecting the stream and iterating on the resulting collection? It will be out of date if an update happened in the meantime, but there's no way to prevent that except blocking the update.